# ¿Cómo envío datos por POST sin formulario?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un buscador el cual envía los datos por post. El problema está en que aparte en otra página tengo una tabla con datos y necesito que envíe datos por `POST` mediante un enlace sin tener que escribir la información a solicitar. ¿Cómo se haría en el buscador?

Este enlace me genera un certificado el cual no debe visualizar el dato enviado por la *URL*. Ya que puede ser modificado fácilmente por cualquier tercero, descarto enviarlo por `GET`, porque se ve la información en la *URL* y es lo que quisiera evitar.

Esta es la parte del código que tengo, pero no me funciona:

```
            <a onclick="Enviar()" href="reportes/plantilla.php" target="_blank">
                <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"> </i> 
            </a> 
        </div> 
    <?php } ?> 
    </div> 
    <br><br> 
    <?php include('footer.php'); ?> 
</html> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Enviar() { 
        document.form2.submit(); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes usar ajax para hacer el post y no refrescar la página.

Comment: ¿Como seria?, me podrias dar un ejemplo, ya que no manejo muy bien el JS

Comment: Te adjunto un fiddle con un ejemplo de cómo utilizar ajax para hacer peticiones.

https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/2nmz8Lbq/

Comment: Tienes que poner un código, lo más corto posible pero que sea lo bastante completo como para reproducir el problema. Mira sobre [MC y Ve](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar Jquery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 4):

Mediante ajax, envías a la URL y pasas los parámetros por post. Prueba y si tienes problemas añade el código para que podamos guiarte.

Comment: Hola Carmen, aunque ha pasado un tiempo, tu respuesta fue reportada por ser de baja calidad, pero puedes editar tu respuesta añadiendo información adicional para que así cumpla con los lineamientos de la comunidad. Un saludo!